# node js passport js change user's password

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm creating an application using node js. in this application i already completed user login and registration via passport js. So now i need to provide access to the logged user to change there password. So i'm trying to do this in my own way but when i run this process the changed password doesn't updated and save it to the logged user's mongoose document. I'll provide the code that i used to that process. So i'm requesting you guys please let me know how can i do this in with my program.

This is my POST route for the change password.

```
app.post('/changePass/:hash', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    cph.findOne({hash: req.params.hash}).populate('userId', "local.password -_id").exec(function(err, hash){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(validator.isEmpty(req.body.currentPassword) || validator.isEmpty(req.body.newPassword) || validator.isEmpty(req.body.confirmPassword)){
            res.render('admin/settings/pages/cup/cpf', {
                user: req.user,
                message: 'Fields must be required',
                data: hash
            });
        }
        else {
            if(!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.currentPassword, hash.userId.local.password)){
                res.render('admin/settings/pages/cup/cpf', {
                    user: req.user,
                    message: 'Current password is incurrect',
                    data: hash
                });
            }
            else {
                if(req.body.newPassword != req.body.confirmPassword){
                    res.render('admin/settings/pages/cup/cpf', {
                        user: req.user,
                        message: 'New password and confirm password do not match',
                        data: hash
                    });
                }
                else {
                    cph.update({$set:{'userId.local.password': bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.confirmPassword, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null)}}, function(){
                        console.log('Success')
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the mongoose collection that creating a hash to change the password sending as a combined link to the logged user's email.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var cpHashSchema = Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    hash: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('changepasswordHash', cpHashSchema);
```

This is the user's collection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = Schema({
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    first: {
        type: String
    },
    last: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    local: {
        username: {
            type: String
        },
        password: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    joined: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    usertype: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user'
    }
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

These are the source code that i'm using to build this application. So guys please help me to complete this application.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you trying to update `changepasswordHash` collection with fields from another table. MongoDB couldn't update related records.

You have to update `users` collection using userId something like:

```
users.update({_id: hash.userId._id}, {$set: {'local.password': newPass}}, callbackHere)
```

Comment: in this users.update({_id: hash.userId._id} object' what it should do. please explain about it bit more

Comment: Mongoose load your user as 2nd query to users collection. and then add it into hash object. So you have all fields from users collection into `hash.userId` property. Containing your `_id` and other props.